# Gradle task for using wsgen to generate webservice

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, soap, wsgen

I have to generate java webservice from java classes. I am able to generate the same using wsgen using jdk utility wsgen. Now I want to generate the webservices for multiple java classes in bulk using build tool gradle. I would be generate all the classes in a given package structure and then want to use gradle to generate webservices (xsd, wsld and other artifacts)  using gradle.

Please help if anyone has used gradle for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [wsgen ant task](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/wsgen.html) and it's simple to [execute ant tasks in gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html)

It looks like someone's already done it [here](https://github.com/kousen/Making-Java-Groovy/blob/master/appC/GenericCalculatorService/build.gradle#L32)